# JQuery dropdown with Paging

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdown figured as below:

[image]

**The question is:** 
i want only 3 items in drop it needs to be in javascript

the dropdown itselfs is based on `ul li` structure.

so what i was thinking is to render all items and than split them into groups of ul's
but i dont know how to realize that in javascript (JQuery) `.each(function(){});`
when the user clicks on the arrow buttons at the buttom it needs to show the second 3 elements / (Groups) in the dropdown.

I hope someone here has a nice idea how to realize this.

http://jsfiddle.net/9pBgZ/18/

Comment: [Please don't add](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/135887) "hello" / "thanks" / "regards" to your questions. Please also make an effort to perform proper capitalization, as it makes questions easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

First hide all the li's with css (display: none;) use jQuery slice (like you said) and then only show the elements you want to show based on the page you are on:

```
$( "li" ).slice( 0, 2).show();
```

or

```
$( "li" ).slice( 3, 5).show();
```

You can also have a look at the [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function.

You can get items by index like this:

```
$( "li" ).get( 0 )
```

You can use a normal for or foreach loop and then select only the items you want to show based on the current selected 'tab'.

**Solution (Thanks FWieP)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var PageNumber = 0;
    var PageSize = 3;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        Paging();

    $("#Back").click(function(){
        PageNumber = PageNumber -1;
        console.log(PageNumber);
        Paging();
    });

    $("#Forward").click(function(){
        PageNumber = PageNumber +1;
        console.log(PageNumber);
        Paging();
    });
});

    function Paging()
    {
       $("#ListItems li").hide();
    var lis = $('#ListItems li').slice(PageNumber*PageSize, (PageNumber*PageSize)+PageSize);
    $(lis).show();
    }


</script>

<div class="Dropdown"> 

<ul id="ListItems">
     <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
</ul>

 <div class="PagingButtons" id="pnlPaging">
   <a class="Back" href="#" id="Back">&lt;</a>
   <a class="Forward" href="#" id="Forward">&gt;</a>
 </div>

</div>
```